# Save values of fields in an object

Tags: jquery

At the moment, I have a list of select boxes with inputs and I would like to save the values in an object when the form is sent, something like this? How could I go about this?

```
var commissions = {
    seller:"Agent",
    percentage:"50"
},
{
    seller:"Crisalix Global",
    percentage:"20"
},
{
    seller:"Support",
    percentage:"30"
};
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="container-seller-commission">
  <div class="row-seller-commission">
    <select name="seller" id="seller" class="select-seller valid">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="4" selected="selected">Agent</option>
      <option value="2">Crisalix Global</option>
      <option value="1">Owner</option>
      <option value="3">Support</option>
    </select>
<input name="percentage" id="percentage" value="100" class="sales-form-input--number sales-form-input--commission valid" type="number">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row-seller-commission">
  <select name="seller" id="seller" class="select-seller valid">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="4" disabled="disabled">Agent</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Crisalix Global</option>
    <option value="1">Owner</option>
    <option value="3">Support</option>
  </select>
<input name="percentage" id="percentage" value="100" class="sales-form-input--number sales-form-input--commission valid" type="number">
</div>
<div class="row-seller-commission">
  <select name="seller" id="seller" class="select-seller valid">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="4" disabled="disabled">Agent</option>
    <option value="2">Crisalix Global</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Owner</option>
    <option value="3" disabled="disabled">Support</option>
  </select>
<input name="percentage" id="percentage" value="100" class="sales-form-input--number sales-form-input--commission valid" type="number">
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: How to save all the values in an object as stated in the question. Thanks

Comment: Aside -- ID's must be unique all your selects and all inputs have the same ID ... that maybe will lead you to issues with the JS code

Comment: and you've tried this and got stuck on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your HTML is definitely invalid. No two elements should share the same ID in an HTML page. It doesn't conform to the standards. You need to use something different e.g. HTML5 attributes, CSS classes etc. for such code.

Coming to the solution for your problem, it can be done similar to the following (assuming that a button generates the list of details):

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var commissions = [];

  $(".row-seller-commission").each(function() {
    var seller = $(this).find("select[name=seller] option:selected").text(),
      percentage = $(this).find("input[name=percentage]").val();

    commissions.push({
      seller: seller,
      percentage: percentage
    });
  });

  console.log(commissions);
});
```

`commissions` will contain the result, as per your need.